# How to initialize weights in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I need to start my net weights as it doesn't predict well and takes a long time to train

this is my code:

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):    
    X_train, Y_train = X[train_index],Y[train_index]
    X_test, Y_test = X[test_index],Y[test_index]

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=4, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=4))
    model.add(Dense(units=16, activation='linear'))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
 
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adamax')     
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=4, epochs=1200, 
              validation_data= (X_test, Y_test) ,verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the [Keras initializers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers). For example, the following code uses Random Normal Initializer:

```
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=1.)
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, kernel_initializer=initializer)
```

If you want to initialize every layer with it, your code should look like this:

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):    
    initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0., stddev=1.)

    X_train, Y_train = X[train_index],Y[train_index]
    X_test, Y_test = X[test_index],Y[test_index]

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=4, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=4, , kernel_initializer=initializer))
    model.add(Dense(units=16, activation='linear', , kernel_initializer=initializer))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear', , kernel_initializer=initializer))
 
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adamax')     
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=4, epochs=1200, 
              validation_data= (X_test, Y_test) ,verbose=1)
```